# Finding fewest bits to store an int in 2s complement

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

This is a homework problem that I'm working on at the moment. What we have to do is look at a passed 32-bit int x and return the fewest bits it would take to store that value in 2s complement.

For example:

```
howManyBits(0) = 1;
howManyBits(-1) = 1;
howManyBits(7) = 4;
howManyBits(-10) = 5;
```

The trouble comes in that I can only use bitwise operators to find this, I cannot have constants larger than a byte, and I cannot have more than 90 operations total.
At the moment, I am able to bit smear a 1 from the most significant bit all the way right, and then I count up every 1 in that. However, since it is a 32-bit int, and I have to shift the int over 1 to the right every time I check for a bit flipped on, the process of counting up the bits takes 90 operations on its own, and since the bit smearing took 20, I am well over the maximum operations.

Also, I am not aloud to use conditionals or loops in my solution.

I know that if I could figure out a log_2 algorithm that could solve it, but I haven't been able to figure that out in bitwise operators only either.

All I would like is a hint at/explanation of a process that would do it in fewer operations, not an actual code solution. Thanks!

Comment: I think sharing your code will bring a lot more attention as well as helpful answers.

Comment: This isn't really a practical programming problem. It's just a puzzle, and it's unlikely to be useful to future visitors to the site.

Comment: Normally, -1 would be `0xFFFFFFFF` in 2's complement. This would imply that you need 32 bits to store it. Or is there something I'm missing here.

Comment: @RaymondChen I must respectfully disagree. This is a common technique used in many data compression algorithms.

Comment: @MultimediaMike There's not much point trying to compress a single integer. Finding the minimum number of bits to encode a *set of integers* is interesting. The constraints of the problem as stated are however quite artificial.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the log_2 of a 32-bit number in 7 operations. See the excellent [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogLookup)

Answer (score 0):

Huston - You have a problem.

i.e.

```
howManyBits(0) = howManyBits(-1) = 1;
```

Therefore you need at least 2 bits for zero. (Or -1)

Comment: No. Think of how 0 is coded in 2s complement. Eight 0s. And -1 is written with eight 1s. Therefore, just a 0 would be equivalent to 0, and just a 1 would be equivalent to -1. So both 0 and -1 need only 1 bit to be represented accurately.

Comment: @FUZxxl - have a little think. You need at least one bit to say that the rest is a value. Also need a bit to differentiate beteen X and Y. i.e. one and zero.

Comment: @Beregond - Use the bits to the max. 00 = 0 , 01 = 1, 10 = -2, 11 = -1 or one bit ease 0 or 1.

Comment: Even in decimal representation the empty word evaluated to zero since the empty sum is zero. If there is no significant value, the result is zero.

Comment: @FUZxxl - You are not getting it. Information requires a value. So the value of zero requires some data. Going to your theory how would you tell apart the value of zero and one? Guess you need a bit.

Comment: @Ed you can't represent 1 with 0 bytes.  Generally, you can represent 2**n values with n bits. 2**0 = 1 so you can represent 1 value (zero) with zero bits. One is simply not representable similary to how 256 is not representable in eight bits.

Comment: @FUZxxl - You said 'Actually, you need only zero bits to encode zero.'. This is incorrect. You need at least ne bit to say it exists and is zero.

Comment: @Ed No, you don't. Really.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework I don't want to give you a direct answer but you're on the right track with the log2 idea.

You can pull it off (for a positive number) with a combination of three operations

```
 1) Shift right 1
 2) Test for 0
 3) Add 1 to a number
```

Hope that's enough to get you there.  Since the source number is going to be in two's complement you'll want to convert it to a positive number first for the above to be effective.

Comment: That's essentially what I'm doing at the moment, but it takes 90 operations to complete.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm not totally clear on what consitutes "an operation" in this case but if code size is not an issue but rather the shear number of instructions that executed for any particular value you could binary search for the highest set bit.  i.e.  shift 16 test, test for 0, if yes than shift 8 and try again, else shift 24, etc...  Depending on how you count that 2-3 operations per test, max 5 rounds, 15 operations.